Не могу получить значения из столбца Dataframe после группировки по этому столбцу
Дан .csv-файл с данными о температуре и влажности воздуха в нескольких городах в определённые даты. Нужно получить средние значения для каждого города и вывести на экран.
Я попробовал сгруппировать данные по городам и найти средние значения для каждого из них. Но когда я пытаюсь получить название города из нового датафрейма, возникает ошибка KeyError: 'city'.
Код моей программы:
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns


data = pd.read_csv("/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/weather.csv")
grouped_data = data.groupby(["city"])[["temp", "hum"]].agg(["mean"])

print("Средняя температура и влажность для каждого города:")
for index, row in grouped_data.iterrows():
    print(f"{row['city']}: {row['temp']['mean']} C, {row['hum']['mean']} %")

Пример .csv-файла:
date,city,temp,hum
2023-01-01,Moscow,-5,80
2023-01-01,London,5,90
2023-01-01,New York,10,70
2023-01-02,Moscow,-4,75
2023-01-02,London,6,85
2023-01-02,New York,9,65
2023-01-03,Moscow,-3,70
2023-01-03,London,7,80
2023-01-03,New York,8,60

P.S. Спасибо всем, кто отвил.
В моём случае нужно было использовать index вместо row['city'] или перед выводом превратить index в столбец, используя .reset_index(inplace=True).
Также, благодаря одному из комментариев я использовал метод .to_string() с аргументом formatters= вместо цикла с выводом. Это более удобно, и вывод выглядит лучше, благодаря выравниванию.
Итоговый код:
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns


data = pd.read_csv("/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/weather.csv")
grouped_data = data.groupby("city")[["temp", "hum"]].agg(["mean"]).droplevel(1, axis=1)
grouped_data.reset_index(inplace=True)

print("Средняя температура и влажность для каждого города:")
print(grouped_data.to_string(formatters={"city": "{}:".format, 
                                         "temp": "{}°, ".format, 
                                         "hum": "{}%".format}, 
                             index=False,
                             header=False))


@CrazyElf MultiIndex([('temp', 'mean'), ( 'hum', 'mean')],)

печать через print() в цикле iterrows() не очень эффективна. попробуйте использовать метод фрейма to_string() с аргументом formatters

@АлексейР так действительно могло быть удобнее, но я не совсем понимаю, как сделать это в моём случае.

как-то так print("Средняя температура и влажность для каждого города:\n" + pd.read_csv("/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/weather.csv").groupby("city", as_index=False)[["temp", "hum"]].agg(["mean"]).droplevel(1, axis=1).to_string(formatters={"city": "{}:".format, "temp": "{}°, ".format, "hum": "{}%".format}, index=False, header=False))

@АлексейР У меня as_index=False почему-то не работает и названия городов остаются в index. Поэтому пришлось добавить grouped_data.reset_index(inplace=True) до вывода с .to_string(). А так ваш ответ мне очень помог, спасибо.

Город попадает в индекс, я сначала не совсем правильно вспомнил. Просто берите его из индекса:
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from io import StringIO

string = """
date,city,temp,hum
2023-01-01,Moscow,-5,80
2023-01-01,London,5,90
2023-01-01,New York,10,70
2023-01-02,Moscow,-4,75
2023-01-02,London,6,85
2023-01-02,New York,9,65
2023-01-03,Moscow,-3,70
2023-01-03,London,7,80
2023-01-03,New York,8,60"""

data = pd.read_csv(StringIO(string))
grouped_data = data.groupby(["city"])[["temp", "hum"]].agg(["mean"])
print("Средняя температура и влажность для каждого города:")
for index, row in grouped_data.iterrows():
    print(f"{index}: {row['temp']['mean']} C, {row['hum']['mean']} %")
            ^^^^^^^

Вывод:
Средняя температура и влажность для каждого города:
London: 6.0 C, 85.0 %
Moscow: -4.0 C, 75.0 %
New York: 9.0 C, 65.0 %


Спасибо, всё получилось )

groupby(..., as_index=False)

@kolyaskywalker если ответ вам помог, отметьте его как принятый. можете так же этот ответ "плюсануть".

@strawdog А, ну или так, да, забыл

@strawdog я сразу плюсанул, только мой голос не отображался из-за низкого рейтинга.

@strawdog ваш способ у меня почему-то не сработал.
